# Help with MySql trigger or alternative

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am trying to bring together two separate designs here so I understand the overall approach may not be ideal.  Basically through user input in PHP table1 and part of table2 is populated and then in turn I need the rest of table2 and table3 to be populated automatically.

I have the following db

[image]

with this trigger

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER new_trigger AFTER INSERT on table2
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table3(att1, DateCreated, DateUpdated)
    VALUES('PG', now(), now());
    UPDATE table2 SET table3Id = table3.LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

although MySQL accepts the trigger as written without any errors I get this error when the app runs:

```
 General error: 1442 Can't update table 'table2' in stored function/trigger 
    because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

I believe this comes from MySQL triggers can't manipulate the table they are assigned to.  So if this is the reason for the error how else can I achieve the same results?

**EDIT: (ANSWER)**

Thanks to the help from mootinator here and in chat.  Here is his solution that works as I need it to.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_trigger BEFORE INSERT on table2
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table3(att1, DateCreated, DateUpdated)
    VALUES('PG', now(), now());
    SET NEW.table3Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

Comment: It might be good to describe the actual situation you have with all the table names and relationships. Perhaps the issue can be solved by some other way, avoiding triggers.

Comment: ypercube I decided to simplify things here posting it as I did.  I will be moving to a better solution once I have the time to rewrite the affected parts of the app but we needed to get something working asap, bandaid or not.

Comment: It seems that @mootinator's answer has solved your problem, fine. From what I understand, you could also try a `transaction` approach. Never issuing an `INSERT` on `table2` but a transaction that inserts first to `table3` and then to `table2` (using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, same way as the trigger does).  This has the advantage that a transaction is atomic, meaning it either fails or succeeds altogether. With a (`BEFORE`) trigger, you can sometimes end with a row inserted in `table3` and then having the INSERT fail to add the row in `table2` leaving the row in `table3` childless.

Comment: @ypercube you make a good point.  Couldn't I just take this logic from the trigger and turn it into a function that is initiated by a trigger?

Comment: My point is to have no triggers at all. Just a `START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO table3 ...; INSERT INTO table2 ...; COMMIT;` And forbid your apps from doing any `INSERT` into `table2`. See here for documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html

Comment: I am familiar with using transactions (initiated through my app) but confused at what you are suggesting as I would have to (as I believe) change my code to initiate the transaction (which a code change will be in the near future).  How else can this transaction be set off without changing my app, or can it be?  I am open for suggestions if I can do this completely in the db.  thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3776/discussion-between-enfield-and-ypercube)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an AFTER trigger because the new change you make would (potentially) cause the AFTER trigger to be run again in an infinite loop.  You have to use a BEFORE trigger to edit the row *before* it gets written.

Try eg:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_trigger BEFORE INSERT on table2
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table3(att1, DateCreated, DateUpdated)
    VALUES('PG', now(), now());
    SET NEW.table3Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

Comment: I have tried a BEFORE trigger also, regardless the same error appears.  Like I said I think the problem is that MySQL triggers can't manipulate the table they are assigned to as other dbs can.

Comment: Did you leave the `UPDATE table2` in the TRIGGER or did you replace it with `NEW.table2Id = table3.LAST_INSERT_ID();`?

Comment: Also, your UPDATE statement refers to the whole table, not a specific row.

Comment: Yes it is a different trigger since you can't update a new record.  I used essentially what you have `INSERT INTO table2(table3ID)
VALUES(table3.LAST_INSERT_ID());`

Comment: That isn't *essentially* what I have.  Changing column values on the inserted row is allowed using the NEW alias is allowed, changing the table some other way isn't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3773/discussion-between-mootinator-and-enfield)